# Create Laravel Nova Lens - Using $this when not in object context

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am trying out larval Nova, particularly the lens

I have followed the guide https://nova.laravel.com/docs/1.0/lenses/defining-lenses.html

but it is complaining about the use of the $this in this line

```
   $query->select($this->columns())
```

with the error

```
$this when not in object context
```

here is the code

```
<?php

namespace App\Nova\Lenses;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Lenses\Lens;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Number;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest;

class MostValuableUsers extends Lens
{
    /**
     * Get the query builder / paginator for the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
    {
        return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
            $query->select($this->columns())
                  ->join('licenses', 'users.id', '=', 'licenses.user_id')
                  ->orderBy('revenue', 'desc')
                  ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name')
        ));
    }

    /**
     * Get the columns that should be selected.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    protected function columns()
    {
        return [
            'users.id',
            'users.name',
            DB::raw('sum(licenses.price) as revenue'),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the fields available to the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function fields(Request $request)
    {
        return [
            ID::make('ID', 'id'),
            Text::make('Name', 'name'),

            Number::make('Revenue', 'revenue', function ($value) {
                return '$'.number_format($value, 2);
            }),
        ];
    }

    /**
     * Get the filters available for the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Illuminate\Http\Request  $request
     * @return array
     */
    public function filters(Request $request)
    {
        return [];
    }

    /**
     * Get the URI key for the lens.
     *
     * @return string
     */
    public function uriKey()
    {
        return 'most-profitable-users';
    }
}
```

Is there something else I need to configure?

Comment: your function is static, so you can't use `$this`

Answer (score 1):

The problem is you use $this in static function (a function that is not aware of `$this` context). I would suggest to create an instance inside your static function (if you really need a static function).

```
namespace App\Nova\Lenses;

use Laravel\Nova\Fields\ID;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Text;
use Laravel\Nova\Lenses\Lens;
use Laravel\Nova\Fields\Number;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;
use Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest;

class MostValuableUsers extends Lens
{
    /**
     * Get the query builder / paginator for the lens.
     *
     * @param  \Laravel\Nova\Http\Requests\LensRequest  $request
     * @param  \Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Builder  $query
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function query(LensRequest $request, $query)
    {
        $mostValuableUser = new MostValuableUsers();

        return $request->withOrdering($request->withFilters(
            $query->select($mostValuableUser->columns())
                  ->join('licenses', 'users.id', '=', 'licenses.user_id')
                  ->orderBy('revenue', 'desc')
                  ->groupBy('users.id', 'users.name')
        ));
    }

    ...
```